# Netbeans auto import in IntelliJ

Tags: netbeans, intellij-idea, import

I'm struggling to find the equivalent to the auto import feature of Netbeans (Ctrl Shift i). I know IntelliJ can import automatically when autocompleting, but is there no way of including/finding imports by keymap?

Comment: Sadly the correct answer seems to be "there isn't an equivalent". I do like Intellij, but its auto import feature drastically needs some work IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA has <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> for **Optimize Imports**.

You can also add new imports for the red code via intention action (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Comment: That is not auto import. It does not import anything! It just re-organizes imports.

Comment: As @Whitecat says, `Ctrl+Alt+O` is not the same as Netbeans' "Fix Imports" command because it doesn't add imports and `Alt+Enter` is done (painstakingly) per class. Even ambiguous classes are handled in NB by cycling through the errors automatically. It's one of two really simple and common pieces of functionality I miss from NB.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is go to (Windows)`Settings > Editor > Auto Import` or (OS X)`Preferences > Editor > Auto Import.`   Then check on `add unambiguous imports on the fly`

Then the next time you push  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> for **Optimize Imports** the unambiguous imports will go in automatically.

[image: Setting screen shot]